# Getting file not found error in C# program?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have used WinBuilder to include support for .NET 3.0/2.0 into Windows PE 3.0. I have made a program that is checking for necessary programs that are in the system folder. I know that diskpart is located at "X:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe" in windows PE. But when I use this code:

```
if (File.Exists(@"X:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe"))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Found it");
}
```

it doesn't find the file. I have tried writing a string of text into a batch file as so:

```
System.IO.WriteAllText(@"X:\temp\diskpart.cmd", "diskpart.exe\npause");
Process proc = new Process;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"X:\temp\diskpart.cmd";
proc.Start();
```

It starts the batch file just fine, but it states that it couldn't find the program diskpart.exe. Odd thing is when I go outside of the program and manually type in X:\temp\diskpart.cmd, it runs the batch file just fine and is able to run diskpart.exe. I have also tried changing the username of the process to SYSTEM, but it still didn't work.

I am aware that native support for .NET in WinPE isn't supported, but I thought I would at least try. Anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Have try to run the process under Current user?

Comment: originally I didn't include the proc.StartInfo.UserName property. So yes.

Comment: Why don't you make your program emit the result of Directory.GetFiles("X:\\", recursive) in order to debug this? Just looking at the code doesn't lead to a resolution. You need to investigate.

Comment: Most likely SYSTEM hasnt got a mapped drive of X. Any mapped drives are session & user specific

Comment: Tried that and the only files that were listed were X:\bootmgr and X:\$WIMDESC. I'm thinking it might be a permissions error, but How do I add permissions for my program?

Answer (score 4):

File.Exists() returns false if you don't have read permissions on the file.

From the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx):

> **true** if the caller has the required permissions and *path* contains the name of an existing file; otherwise, **false**. This method also returns **false** if *path* is null, an invalid path, or a zero-length string. If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns **false** regardless of the existence of *path*.

You almost always want to avoid using File.Exists() in favor of just trying to open the file instead, and catching the exception if it fails. This is true even if you don't intend ever to read or write to the file stream you obtain. This has the nice bonus of allowing you to just use the stream right away as well.

Comment: If the program is ran from the CMD of WinPE, isn't everything ran from SYSTEM? At least in TaskMgr it says the user running the process of my program is SYSTEM.